# how can I manage my Navbar using Angular canactivate guard

Tags: angular

Im a bit confused about managing my Navbar which should not be seen if the user is not authenticated,here is my LoginComponent:

```
          public validLogin:boolean=false;
      
      constructor(private router:Router,private authaervice:AuthService) { }
      signIn(credntials){
        this.authaervice.login(credntials)
         .subscribe(result=>{
             if(result){
              localStorage.setItem('token',result.toString());
              this.validLogin=true;
              return true;
                       }
                  false;
                     })
                     }
         canActivate(): boolean | UrlTree {
                 if(this.validLogin){
                 return true;
                                     }
                 this.router.navigate(['/app-dashboard']);
                }
```

in my app.component.html i have :

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

here is my navbar component:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          
              <img src="assets/leitwind_logo.png" alt="logo">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/app-dashboard">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/app-events">EventLog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/app-turbine-comparison">TurbineComparison</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/app-overview">AccessInfo</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Exit </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
```

now,first of all where should i put my NavBarComponent not be seen by all components if the user is authenticated and how can i manage that?

here is my app.module which i have my routs

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
                   
                      {path:'',component:LoginComponent},
                      {path:'app-events',component:EventsComponent},
                      {path:'app-turbine-comparison',component:TurbineComparisonComponent},
                      {path:'app-dashboard',component: DashboardComponent},
                      {path:'app-overview',component: OverviewComponent}

                                                                     ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

One method to handle this is to have a core component that loads freely on all pages. this typically has your header and footer controls and nothing else.

Between the header and footer insert the Navigation component directive as a child.

On the Navigation component define your nav section and a content section. Insert your router outlet in the content section.

Now to show/hide based on authentication process I found an easy method to set a bool variable called isLoggedIn. I've used a behavoirSubject for this purpose that is set on the return callback from your authentication server/system/process.

Set your authguard to check the login status and divert to unauthorised page if not authenticated or token has expired et al.

```
{ path: 'navigation', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: NavigationComponent },
```

Remember authguards work on URLs and your navigation component is part of every url, so it will fire each url change (which is what you want).

With that in mind you could set your navigation menu / controls etc to be shown conditional on "isLoggedIn" being true. eg. `*ngIf="(dataSvc.loggedIn$ | async)"`

I appreciate this is a bare bones outline explanation, but happy to supply sample code if needed.

Comment: thanks but ngIf part where should be defined ?dataSvc.loggedIn is in my login component?

Comment: Well taking my example, the ngIf is defined in the navigation div that holds your nav menus <nav *ngIf="(dataSvc.loggedIn$ | async) class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you provide me a sample